# Unable to use --screenshot or --print-to-pdf flags using headless mode of Chromium on Ubuntu desktop

Tags: ubuntu, chromium, headless

I am using the headless version of Chrome and Chromium to take screenshots of given pages.
It works fine on Windows and Ubuntu server, but not on an Ubuntu Desktop VM.

I get the error "**Open multiple tabs is only supported when remote debugging is enabled**" on Ubuntu Desktop when I try to take a screenshot (`--screenshot` flag) or to generate a PDF file (`--print-to-pdf` flag).

I could enable remote debugging with the `--remote-debugging-port` flag, but when it is enabled, you can not use the `--screenshot` flag or the `--print-to-pdf` flag.

## Details

### On windows

**Version** :
Google Chrome Version 84.0.4147.125

**Command used** :
`> start chrome --headless --screenshot=%CD%\example_sh.png https://example.com/`

*Note: you have to give a path to the screenshot on windows or else it will not create the file, this is why I added `%CD%\` on Windows only. But this is not the issue here.*

**Command output** :
None

**File generated :**
`Yes`

### On Ubuntu Server

**Version** :

```
$ chromium-browser --version
Chromium 84.0.4147.105 Built on Ubuntu , running on Ubuntu 18.04
```

**Command used** :
`$ chromium-browser --headless --screenshot=example_sh.png https://example.com/`

**Command output** :
`[0812/102830.971006:INFO:headless_shell.cc(615)] Written to file example_sh.png.`

**File generated :**
`Yes`

### On Ubuntu Desktop

**Version** :

```
$ chromium-browser --version
Chromium 84.0.4147.105 snap
```

**Command used** :
`$ chromium-browser --headless --screenshot=example_sh.png https://example.com/`

**Command output** :
`[0812/123941.367535:ERROR:headless_shell.cc(174)] Open multiple tabs is only supported when remote debugging is enabled.`

**File generated :**
*`No`*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An answer has been given for the same question on SO : https://stackoverflow.com/a/63514185/12182226

Basically, instead of the `chromium-browser` or `chromium` command, you have to use the value of chromium's `Executable Path` shown in the `chrome://version` page. For instance, `/snap/chromium/1260/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chrome`.

To take a screenshot:
`/snap/chromium/1260/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chrome --headless --screenshot=example_sh.png https://example.com/`

Comment: Doesn't seem like you can execute chrome directly: `/snap/chromium/current/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chrome: error while loading shared libraries: libnss3.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is related to the *snap* version of Chromium on your desktop VM. Replace it with the same `.deb` package used on your server and everything should just work as expected.

Comment: This could be a good workaround if I were the only one using these flags, but this won't do as a solution, as I'm calling a command using them inside some code that is part of a library that is shared with other people.